# Delphi IDE main window height limit?

Tags: delphi, ide, height, delphi-11-alexandria

How can I set the Delphi IDE main window height to be greater than the height of the monitor on which it is displayed?

I have 4 HD monitors, arranged in a square, one monitor in each corner.

If I start Delphi (v11 Alexandria on Win 11 Pro, but I doubt that matters) in, say, the top-left monitor then I can drag the right-hand edge of the IDE main window all the way to the far right of the top-right monitor. So, the IDE can be as wide as two monitors if I want.

However, if I try to drag the bottom edge of the IDE main window to increase its height beyond the monitor height then I cannot do it. The window refuses to get any higher than the height of the monitor on which the title bar is displayed (1080 pixels in my case).

It behaves as if there is a hard limit on the height of the IDE (not allowed to be greater than the height of the monitor). If this is the case then I do not understand it - why allow the user to increase the IDE width across multiple monitors but not the height?

If anyone knows how to work around this restriction then I would love to learn about it.

Comment: Can you make a Notepad window taller than a single monitor?

Comment: Yes, all other applications can do it. I have just confirmed that with Notepad, Explorer, Word and this browser.

Comment: You should probably enter a report at https://quality.embarcadero.com

Comment: Window sizes should be limited to the **desktop** size. Maybe the IDE window has a reason to be bound to a **screen** height. Have you tested a higher desktop resolution, so your screen height becomes more than 1080 px?

Comment: Yes, just tried that. The IDE happily occupies the height of any screen but will not vertically extend into another screen. It has no trouble extending horizontally across multiple screens.

Comment: On a 4K monitor with orientation set to "Portrait" the IDE happily uses a window height of 3840 pixels, so 1080 pixels (or even 1200 or 2160) is not the limit. It appears that there is some code in the IDE that restricts the height to the height of one monitor. As fpiette said: File a bug report.

Comment: OK, thank you all for your responses. I will see what Embarcadero have to say about it.
If they come up with anything useful I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Embarcadero and they logged the issue as RS-110947. They also sent me a package to install - and this has fixed the problem. However, they have asked me not to upload this package to StackOverflow because it is not official (just something the support agent wrote to test what was possible). It will be officially fixed in a future release.